# gradle: different srcDirs for intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a **gradle** based project with several subprojects that has a folder in the project root with some shared test files. I can push these into the subprojects using **subprojects.sourceSets**.

```
subprojects {
 sourceSets {
     test {
         resources {
             srcDirs = ["${rootDir}/resources"]
         }
      }
   }
```

Unf when I import this into IntelliJ it gives me an error:

```
Error:Can't register given path of type 'TEST_RESOURCE' because it's out of content root.
Content root: '/Users/me/git/platform/mix'
Given path: '/Users/me/git/platform/resources'
```

If I set the **srcDirs** to the path without the **${rootDir}** IntelliJ is happy but then gradle doesn't work.

It looks like the 'idea' plugin might be helpful but I'm not clear on how to set one path for gradle builds and another for IntelliJ.

Suggestions?